# Android Studio AndroidRunTime Fatal Exception Error

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Some errors that I get through android studio look like this:

```
2023-02-17 00:57:35.696  5030-5030  ViewRootIm...nActivity] pid-5030                             I  ViewPostIme pointer 1
2023-02-17 00:57:35.703  5030-5030  System.out              pid-5030                             I  connect send
2023-02-17 00:57:35.705  5030-8851  System.out              pid-5030                             I  attempting connection
2023-02-17 00:57:35.705  5030-8851  System.out              pid-5030                             I  Socket created
2023-02-17 00:57:35.707  5030-8851  AndroidRuntime          pid-5030                             E  FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-4
                                                                                                    Process: com.example.porte, PID: 5030
```

(Specifically AndroidRuntime)

Is there any documentation anywhere to find out what kind of error this is?

Comment: Can you share the whole stacktrace you got from the logcat?

Comment: @rockar06 There is everything pertaining to the pid

Comment: The data you have provided is not enough to drill into any conclusive solution.

Comment: @TharakaDevinda Then what is enough data, I don't know what the issue is pertaining to, I can tell which thread it is in, but without knowing even if their is a way to find the specific error I can't do anything